# How to convert timestamp locally according to our location

Tags: go

```
startTime := time.Unix(logUserDetail[k].LogTime, 0)
startTimeOfLog := startTime.String()[11:16]
```

I have time in timestamp format and it is in UTC time zone. I want to convert this time to the local timezone according to our location.

logUserDetail[k].LogTime is in timestamp(1499335473)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(t Time) In()` ([Golang documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In)) to convert `startTime` to use your local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Local function for time structs: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Local

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
"time"
)
func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(startTime.Local())
}
```